# ORACLE : How to use manual ID generated using MAX ID with Oracle Merge statement insert query

Tags: oracle, merge, insert

I have 2 tables like below,

Master_Data_1

```
Id     Name
1      AAA 
2      BBB
3      DDD
4      CCC
```

Master_Data_2

```
Id     Name     Upt_Flg
1      DDD      False
2      EEE      False
3      FFF      False
```

both tables have same ID but different Name, and ID field is neither auto incremented nor sequence. But ID is a not null primary key column which will be generated based on MAX ID logic.

In this case i am trying to merge Master_Data_1 table with Master_Data_2 table using oracle merge statement.

So i am having issue in WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN case, i am trying to insert not matched records in to Master_data_2 table from master_data_1 table. 
In this scenario ID in Master_Data_2 table will not be auto incremented, and also i cannot use the source table ID here because it will lead to unique constraint exception.

Note : I don't want to alter a table to make ID auto increment or adding sequence for ID.

**Expected Output in Master_Data_2 table using merge query:**

```
Id     Name     Upt_Flg
1      DDD      TRUE
2      EEE      False
3      FFF      False
4      AAA      False
5      BBB      False
6      CCC      False
```

is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You are not as clear as you should be. You forget to mention if the `name` column is *unique* in both tables. If not your question (and provided answers) are questionable, if so you **do not need `MERGE`**, a simple `INSERT` of missing names with assignment of a new MAX based ID's is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I guess ROW_NUMBER analytic function might help you here.

```
MERGE INTO Master_Data_2 md2
USING (SELECT (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Master_Data_2) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) new_id
             ,name
       FROM Master_Data_1
      ) md1
ON (md2.name = md1.name)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
                  SET Upt_flg = 'TRUE'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (md2.id, md2.name)
VALUES (Md1.new_id, md1.name);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=900e2d18fe013fe2b14fb29f5ba25afd) is the fiddle

Comment: I think this will skip ids if there is matching record exists. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=28035616193be2852a2898cb5c4f61b0) .. but yes, as per sample data it is correct.

Comment: @Tejash, Thank you so much. Do you have any other approach to achieve the same?

Comment: Yes, we can achieve it using insert and minus operator. See my answer.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Add `where` clause in your source table [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=14caa1a220541e9060488e33457a6563).

Comment: @AnkitBajpai thanks for your suggestion, but as **Tejash** comment it will skip the id on matching records existing case. And as per **PonderStibbons** comment if we add where condition for **Name not in** then it will not work for update statement . Thanks.

Comment: @user2825564, Can you just update your question with expected output?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai i have updated my questions with adding one update column for master_data_2 table and expected result .

Comment: @user2825564, I have updated my answer to reflect your requirement. However why do you want to update the ID. An id is an id by anyways even if it is dropping some numbers in between.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve it using `INSERT` and `MINUS` operator as following:

```
insert into master_data_2
select 
(select max(id) from master_data_2) + row_number() over (order by 1),
name 
from
(select name from master_data_1
minus
select name from master_data_2)
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=40f7ff0559a050e558d01af514eba414)

Cheers!!

Comment: it is like normal insert query , i need to apply this case in merge statement which will also have the update statement. If my understanding is wrong can you please give the full merge with update statement. Lets add one flag in master_data_2 as upt_flg, if the name is same i have to update the flag as true, else i have to insert the names as mentioned above. Thanks